# is this the wrong/inefficient way to create and use PDO objects in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm messing around with an example site from teamtreehouse's PHP/MySQL project... In their 'model' code, they have all DB calls inside functions inside a file called products.php.. each of these functions will create a new PDO object by importing an include file.. for example:

```
function get_products_recent() {

    require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");  //this instantiates a new PDO object called $db

    try {
        $results = $db->query("
                SELECT name, price, img, sku, paypal
                FROM products
                ORDER BY sku DESC
                LIMIT 4");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database. get_products_recent";
        exit;
    }

    $recent = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $recent = array_reverse($recent);

    return $recent;
}
```

But I was finding the db queries were slowing down page loads significantly..

After some googling I found the PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true attribute that can be added to the PDO constructor... and that has sped up the pages loads back to 'normal'..

But is this wrong/inefficient practice for real-world scenarios..? is there a better way to be opening and using the PDO object rather than creating a new PDO object inside every function call that makes a db call?

Comment: There is no *normal practise* though I would only create one PDO resource and pass that around where required.

Comment: this @Phil ...  maybe I should have phrased the question as 'is doing it this way inefficient and should I be doing it another way' (such as you describe). I'm trying to make this as MVC'ish as possible by keeping all the DB calls within this set of functions / this file..  Would it make more sense to just declare the PDO object at the beginning of the file as 'global' to the file,.. or by adding a PDO param to every function in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it wrong.

Yes, you have to declare **single** PDO object at the beginning of the file and use it throughout the whole application. This is a very basic rule, that have to be followed despite any circumstances. This is not the "best", this is the only acceptable design.

In fact, you are practically killing your your DB server, opening as **many** connections as many times PDO object is created. And time consumed for the connection is not the only problem - on a live server max number of connections will be reached immediately, and using persistent connection will make it even worse.

And yes, you should have titled your question other way, as people here *never* bother to read the question body but judge the question by its title only.

Setting persistent connection is a false solution. This feature has its own reasons to use which has noting to do with correcting initially wrong design.

The reason why you get your page loading slow is just creating a **new database connection** every time you run a query. As simple as that. So - create a PDO object only once and then pass it as a parameter (as most convenient and less hated by fanatics solution).

Comment: I agree with your answer. I just upvoted it. However, I don't understand your objection to prepared statements. Can you explain why you feel that using prepared statements would not enhance the DB performance when the PHP documentation says it will?

Comment: Speaking of reusing prepared statements between separate HTTP calls, it's simple: PHP operates prepared statements via statement object. But you obviously cannot use once created object in another instance, as it will die with whole PHP script due discrete PHP execution. So, there is no way to reach previously prepared statement and reuse it and thus one is bound to prepare it again. Speaking of reusing the same statement during the same call - as I told it before, it seldom can be used and thus considered insignificant.

Comment: Speaking of documentation - I suspect it's just a lie intended to lure people into prepared statements.

Answer (score -2):

I typically create a database connection class. Usually it's a singleton. The PDO object is a protected property of the class. My model files will extend this class. Thus, I have a single PDO object which is secure because it can only be accessed by classes which extend the superclass.

Are you using prepared statements? This will enhance performance. It will also greatly reduce the risk of sqli attacks.

Here are some other things to consider when optimizing DB performance:

- what storage engine are you using?
- what are your mysql configuration settings?
- are you using primary keys?
- can you use a join instead of performing multiple queries?
- can you cache queries?
- do you have any particularly slow queries which could possibly be refactored?

HTH -- n

Comment: Where did you get that idea that prepared statements enhance performance?

Comment: This is a fact. Read up on the topic. When a query is performed the SQL code has to be compiled. A prepared statement is only compiled once. I don't mind you asking me that question, but know what you're talking about before you down vote an answer.

Comment: A web application that runs the same query more than once is most likely a poorly designed one. So, for the sanely designed PHP application that runs every query only once - how it's possible to make it any faster with prepared statements?

Comment: What are you talking about? Unless the query is cached it will be repeated every time a user hits the page that calls it. If the query uses a prepared statement it will only be compiled once, thereby greatly enhancing the DB performance of the app.

Comment: I am talking of of using prepared statements in PHP, which I use many years already, while you apparently didn't try it even once - as you should have known that it's impossible to execute the query that has been prepared in the other call. For the obvious reasons due to nature of PHP.

Comment: Read what the official PHP documentation has to say about prepared statements. It is exactly what I've been trying to explain to you: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Just try to use it :)  You will see.

Comment: Sounds wrong to have a model class that extends a singleton. Did you mean *consume* instead of *extend*?

Comment: @Phil No, I meant extend. The PDO object in the super class is protected. the models extend this class thereby gaining access to the PDO object.